# Change Meteor email validation link and route

Tags: validation, email, hyperlink, meteor, account

When Meteor sends the email with the link to validate the account, the link looks like this:
**"//localhost:3000/#/verify-email/jOCevGxWbWQfcGL7KAtQ"**
If you click on the link it validates the account as a charm, but it sends the user to the 'ROOT' template.
I want to change this route. Clicking on the validation link have to route the user to another page, another then root route ('/').
I have tryied changing the link adding a new template:
**"//localhost:3000/template/#/verify-email/jOCevGxWbWQfcGL7KAtQ"**
... and it works partially.
It verifies the account perfectly and routes the user to the right template... but this solution breaks all the images in this "template".
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I have done.
I've stopped concatenating the url and made a dynamic link within the rendered function to route the app to the page I want in the moment of the e-mail link validation.

Thanks Askhat your answer was right on the spot, because the images src need the "/" to work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you got it, but I'll drop another option.  To change the URL you can do something like:

```
Accounts.urls.verifyEmail = function (token) {
    return Meteor.absoluteUrl('verify-email/'+token);
};
```

And even better, you can eliminate that horribly long link by changing the email html:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html = function(user, url) {
    var prettyEmail = "<a href="+url+">Click Me!</a>";
    return prettyEmail;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your images are referenced correctly. If your image is referenced using relative paths use an absolute path instead:

i.e

```
<img src="image.jpg"/> 
<img src="images/image.jpg"/>
```

should be

```
<img src="/image.jpg"/> 
<img src="/images/image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Yes they are all just like you suggested.
What is weird is that the images are only broken if accessed by that link I've concatenated (adding a template), if you get into that page by normal access all images are fine.

Comment: if you check the links with the chrome webkit inspector and open them up in a new window what do you get?

Comment: I understand your question and the image is ok, unless it is shown through the concatenated link.
I think I should not simply concatenate this link in the first place.
Maybe there is a way to say to the validation engine that the page to go after the validation is X instead of "/".

Thanks for your help Askhat.